# how to reset firebase auth password in react native

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native

I want to know how to reset password of firebase email authentication password in my react-native project . I like to sent an email for resetting the password. How to do that using the following method

```
  firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```js
 forgotPassword = (Email) => {
    firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(Email)
      .then(function (user) {
        alert('Please check your email...')
      }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e)
      })
  }
```

An email should be passed for this forgot password method.

Comment: Worked for me by just removing "firebase." at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

i think the answer above is old version, for me it doesn't work...
try that way

```
import {signInWithEmailAndPassword, sendPasswordResetEmail,} from firebase/auth";
import { auth,  } from "../config/firebase";

const forgotPassword = (Email) => {

    console.log("reset email sent to " + Email);
    sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, Email, null)
        .then(() => {
            alert("reset email sent to " + Email);
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
};
```

that's what works for me...

Answer (score 0):

with react-native-flash-message and formik example

```js
        import {Formik} from 'formik';
        import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
        import { showMessage } from "react-native-flash-message";
      const initialFormValues = {
        useremail:'',
      }
             async function handleFormSubmit(formValues){
            if(formValues.useremail == ''){
              showMessage({
                message: 'Lütfen Alanları Doldurunuz.',
                type: "danger",
              });
            }
            else{
                await auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(formValues.useremail)
                    .then(()=> {
                        showMessage({
                            message: 'E-mailinizi kontrol ediniz.',
                            type: "success",
                          });
                        navigation.goBack();
                    }).catch(function (e) {
                        showMessage({
                            message: authErrorMessageParser(e),
                            type: "danger",
                          });
                    })
            }
          }


             async function handleFormSubmit(formValues){
            if(formValues.useremail == ''){
              showMessage({
                message: 'Lütfen Alanları Doldurunuz.',
                type: "danger",
              });
            }
            else{
                await auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(formValues.useremail)
                    .then(()=> {
                        showMessage({
                            message: 'E-mailinizi kontrol ediniz.',
                            type: "success",
                          });
                        navigation.goBack();
                    }).catch(function (e) {
                        showMessage({
                            message: authErrorMessageParser(e),
                            type: "danger",
                          });
                    })
            }
          }
```

```js
<Formik
        initialValues={initialFormValues}
        onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
      >
        {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, values }) => (
        <>
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.textInput_view}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={handleChange('useremail')}
                placeholder='E-posta Giriniz...'
                value={values.useremail}
                keyboardType='email-address'
                autoCapitalize='none'
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button_container}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.button2}
                  onPress={()=>navigation.goBack()}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.button2_text}>Geri</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.button}
                  onPress={handleSubmit}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.button1_text}>E-mail Gönder</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View> 

        </ScrollView>
        </>)}
      </Formik>
```