# React native firebase reset user password email throws a permissions Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a long running react native app that relies on firebase login to authenticate it's users via password/email. No other auntentication mechanic has been used so far. The `Forgot your password` feature came much later.

I'm trying to reset the user's password using the `firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email)` method that has appeared in several issues (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515444/how-to-reset-firebase-auth-password-in-react-native))

That call errors out with `Missing or insufficient permissions` which is an error I saw before when trying to use certain firebase features with an user that was not authenticated... but the user is meant to be unauthenticated when resetting the password.

A simplification of what I'm doing is

```
  const resetPass = useCallback(async email => {
    try {
      await firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
      Alert.alert(`An email has been sent to the email address ${email}`)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }, [])
```

Calling that with the press of a button providing the corresponding email loaded in a field, consistently errors out with `Missing or insufficient permissions` and once or twice after multiple attempts it errors out with something along the lines of `email already in use`

I tried taking the call server side on firebase functions (where the firebase admin api does not expose a similar method to this one) and several variations of the above function. I got no idea of what's wrong or what to do, maybe something wrong with the configuration of my firebase rules?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

EDIT: For clarification When I mentioned I did variations of the above function I meant the resetPass function, I tried to check if the email existed in our db before the call to `sendPasswordResetEmail` to make sure it wasn't something that did not exist and minor things like that

Comment: You said you tried making the call server side. What was the result

Comment: The admin package for server side functions does not expose this API. I could probably use the firebase regular package to try it out, but it's very probably not meant to be done this way